# Django custom url using rest framework

Tags: django, url, routes

I have a model ...

```py
class Person(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30),
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I'm using React on the frontend and using json to deal with my data. So in my `urls.py` file I'm using `drf-extensions` I'm using it because it allows me to do some nested routing but I am having trouble now trying to router correctly if I want all people by name from my database.

For instance, I have a `viewset`

```py
class PersonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = PersonSerialzer
  queryset = Person.objects.all()
```

And I am getting all the data back from my table but I want to have this and also be able to hit an endpoint where I can get back all rows with the same first name. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

u could try django filter

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

```
class PersonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = PersonSerialzer
  queryset = Person.objects.all()
  filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
  filterset_fields = '__all__'
```

```
api/person?first_name=bob
```